# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I know there are many questions out there that are like this one, but I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong. I've checked multiple times for typos in both my code and database. This is my PHP code I've written to submit my form details to the database:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";

if(!empty($_POST))

{

    if(isset($_POST["email"], $_POST["username"], $_POST["type"], $_POST["question"]))
    {
         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
         $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
         $type = test_input($_POST["type"]);
         $question = test_input($_POST["question"]);
         $premium = ($_POST["premium"]);
         $member = ($_POST["member"]);
        if ($member != "NO") 
        {
             $member = "YES";
        }

    }
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($username) && !empty($type) && !empty($question))
    {

        $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Submissions (Email, Username, Type, Question, Member, Premium, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");

        $insert->bind_param("ssssss", $email, $username, $type, $question, $member, $premium);
        if($insert->execute())
        {
            header("Location: landing.php");
            die();
        }
    }
}
function test_input($data) 
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

When I var_dump error call, it returned NULL, but I don't understand what that means. The connection to my database is also a success. These are my database columns: "Email", "Username", "Type", "Question", "Member", "Premium", "Date"
Everything is a varChar except Question and Date. Question is a text and Date is a datetime.
Also, the form fields are as followed: email, username, and question...these are input fields. type is a drop down, member and premium are check boxes.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, your `$insert` is not an object. This is most probably caused by the fact that you use [mysql keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html) as column names (very bad practice). If you must continue to use those names surround them in backticks. (Thanks [u_mulder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553888/u-mulder))

```
$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Submissions (Email, Username, `Type`, Question, Member, Premium, `Date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
```

Comment: Hmm, I changed the Type and Date to something else, but I am still getting the same error for some reason...

Comment: @Razer Well check the error message, your query is failing for some reason.

Comment: When I use var_dump the error it's returning is: NULL

Comment: @Razer what is the exact output of `var_dump($insert)` after `$db->prepare`? Additionally, all examples in the documentation suggest the use of prepare like `if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))`, if you want to avoid the error you should do that.

Comment: The exact error of the output of var_dump is: NULL 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in.....

Comment: @Razer `$insert` can not be `NULL`, [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) states that `mysqli::prepare()` will return either a statement or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong in sql query. If the sql statement sent to it is invalid in the current DB, `prepare()` will then return false.

You can verify it by adding this.

```
if(!$insert){
  echo "Prepare statement failed";
}
```